# Initialize a Rails 3 plugin gem on installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm creating a RubyGem, and I'm wondering if there's any way I can set it up so that when it's listed in a `Gemfile` and someone runs `bundle install`, my gem can copy some files into the Rails path. This would save the user from having to type `rails generate blah`, where `blah` is the name of a generator in my gem.

Is there a callback that the current version of Bundler runs when it installs a gem?

Answer (score 0):

The gem is installed system-wide so it has no knownledge of the project you are using.

The only way to accomplish this is to package it as a plugin and install it as plugin, not a gem. In this case you can provide an `install.rb` hook.